# Python script ignoring args passed to it in Github Workflow

Tags: python, github-actions

I am trying to run a python script with custom args in a Github workflow.

When my script runs on a local machine it uses the package `python-git-info` to retreive the current git commit and pass it to the logger. But within the workflow, I can get the commit using `$(git rev-parse "$GITHUB_SHA")`. I want to pass that to my script as an arg.

But my script always ignores the passed arg and refers to the default value. What am I missing?

Github workflow:

```sh
# This workflow will install Python dependencies, run tests and lint with a single version of Python
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-python-with-github-actions

name: Performance Checker

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ labeled ]

jobs:
  build:
    if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'breaker' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Test performance of all algorithms to ensure nothing broke
      run: |
        python train.py --git_commit=$(git rev-parse "$GITHUB_SHA") --load_config=configs/*
```

Relevant python arg:

```py
parser.add_argument(
    '--git_commit',
    type=str,
    default=gitinfo.get_git_info()['commit'],
    help='current git commit')
```

Error from workflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 74, in <module>
    default=gitinfo.get_git_info()['commit'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This error mesasge indicates to me that the script ignores the passed args and refers to the default value. Any help or insight would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `git rev-parse "$GITHUB_SHA"` as a separate step and check the output?

Comment: I did, and I get the commit value. So when I do `echo "COMMIT $(git rev-parse "$GITHUB_SHA")"` I get `COMMIT 9940feaa831a52380cf74a5dc69c12bf47bc56f9`.

Comment: I even tried passing any random string, but the script always defers to the default value. I don't have any way to check if the input is actually a commit or not. My code just accepts any string passed so I dont know why this behavior is happening.

Comment: Maybe add `set -v` before running the script so you can see what exactly is executed

Comment: I just understood what's going on. I'm posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error:

```
  File "train.py", line 74, in <module>
    default=gitinfo.get_git_info()['commit'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

You are calling `gitinfo.get_git_info()` anyway (since you pass its value to `parser.add_argument()`), it returns `None` and you try to access `None['commit']`, which is why you get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Try to use `default=None` and call `gitinfo.get_git_info()` only if the value of the `git_commit` parameter is `None`.

Comment: I'll try your solution in a moment, but I'm a little confused. Why is `gitinfo.get_git_info()` being called anyway? Doesn't default only run if no argument is provided?

Comment: It's *used* only if no argument is provided, but when you call `parser.add_argument()` you pass a value to `default`. This is when `gitinfo.get_git_info()['commit']` is evaluated.